# Create an algorithm whose recurrence is T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + O(n^2)

Tags: python, algorithm

How do I go about problems like this one: `T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/4) + O(n^2)`

I am able to use two for loops which will give me the `O(n^2)`, right?

Comment: Hint: use recursion, just like in the definition of *T(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

To interpret the equation, read it in English as: "the running time for an input of size n equals the running time for an input of size n/3, plus the running time for an input of size n/4, plus a time proportional to n^2".

Writing code that runs in time proportional to n^2 is possible using nested loops, for example, though it's simpler to write a single loop like `for i in range(n ** 2): ...`.

Writing code that runs in time equal to the time it takes for the algorithm with an input of size n/3 or n/4 is even easier - just call the algorithm recursively with an input of that size. (Don't forget a base case for the recursion to terminate on.)

Putting it together, the code could look something like this:

```py
def nonsense_algorithm(n):
    if n <= 0:
        print('base case')
    else:
        nonsense_algorithm(n // 3)
        nonsense_algorithm(n // 4)
        for i in range(n ** 2):
            print('constant amount of text')
```

I've used integer division (rounding down) because I don't think it makes sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would use `for` and `range(start, stop, steps)`, maybe with a simple to understand algorithm, similar to:

```
def algorithm_n2(n: int) -> int:
    """Returns an integer for a O(N2) addition algorithm

    :n: must be a positive integer
    """
    if n < 1:
        return False

    output = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            output += n * 2

    for i in range(0, n, 3):
        output += n / 3

    for i in range(0, n, 4):
        output += n / 4

    return int(output)


# Test
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(algorithm_n2(24))
```

> ## Using `print()` inside a method is not a best practice.

#### Output

```
27748
```

Comment: This satisfies T(n) = O(n/3) + O(n/4) + O(n^2), which of course is just T(n) = O(n^2). Not what the question asked for.

Comment: Note also that string concatenation is not the best choice of O(1) operation to use - it only happens to be O(1) in CPython because of a particular optimisation that allows a string to be mutable when there is only one reference to it.

Comment: "Using `print()` inside a method is not a best practice" - very disputable, but the task here isn't to write production code anyway. The algorithm is obviously completely useless except for having a running time satisfying the required recurrence relation (which unfortunately, this one doesn't).